# How can I reference a SharePoint attribute within my selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2010

I currently have 500 SharePoint list items displayed on a page. There are attributes assigned to these list items, such as "EMail". (These can be seen when viewing the list item in the browsers dev tools)

When I click on a button, I want to extract the "EMail" details from the visible list items on the page.

Currently I have:

```
$('.container:visible').each(function() {
                    emailString += $(this).text() + "; ";
                });
```

This will essentially pull through the data from the visible containers with the visible text.

How can I pull through only the visible containers EMail attribute so that when I click on a button, it displays the emails of all list items?

(I have the click event sorted, I just need the extraction)

Thanks all.

Comment: does `$(this).attr("EMail")` not work?

Comment: You wouldn't believe that I just got that working. I spent so long looking at it that I was completely blind to the obvious. Thanks Batman. (that sounds cool...)

Comment: I'll put it in an actual answer, if you would accept for future reference..

Comment: Yeah, go for it. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the selector inside the `each` function like so:

```
$('.container:visible').each(function() {
    emailString += $(this).attr("EMail") + "; ";
});
```